# Clojure: get image pixels without displaying

Tags: graphics, clojure, quil

In Quil, I would like to give the `draw` function a bunch of specifications for rectangles, and "draw" those rectangles - I don't want to actually see the rectangles, I just want an array of pixels to compare against a different image.

Something like

```
(difference (get-pixels (draw [[0 0 10 10] <more rectangles here>]))
            target-image-pixels)
```

Is Quil just the wrong choice for this? I'm having a hard time figuring out how to accomplish this in Clojure.